# MATLAB arrayfun on GPU with parfor loop

Tags: matlab, gpu, parfor

I am doing some heavy computational work using `arrayfun` with GPU in MATLAB.

My code looks like this

```
N = 2000;
dp = 0.005;
p1 = [0:dp:1];
p2 = [0:dp:1];
pB = [0:dp:2];
[p1,p2,pB] = meshgrid(p1,p2,pB);
p1 = gpuArray(p1);
p2 = gpuArray(p2);
pB = gpuArray(pB);
A = zeros(N,1);
parfor i = 1:N
       A(i) = arrayfun(@MYFUN,p1,p2,pB);
end
```

First, I am surprised that for `N=2000`, the `parfor` almost takes the same time as the ordinary `for` loop (when using `parfor`, it seems that my MATLAB connects to 6 workers). Is that because my laptop only has 1 GPU, so `parfor` isn't helping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parfor` isn't running on the GPU rather it runs multiple "workers" on the available cores of your computer CPU. In general the GPU cores cannot serve as matlabpool/parpool workers.

If you have multiple GPU's you can use the `parfor` combined with `spmd` in order to run it on the GPU. [mathwork answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/36235-parfor-on-gpu) but this is in case you want to execute a specific function on the GPU.

Comment: The problem here I suspect is not that `parfor` workers can't use the GPU - rather, that there's only 1 GPU and that all the worker MATLAB processes are contending for it. The code as written is (attempting to be) 2-level parallelism - separate cores initiate individual `arrayfun` calls in parallel, each of which could run simultaneously across multiple GPUs.

Comment: @Edric I agree that the fact that there is only 1 GPU is not allowing the parallel-behaviour desired; But the fact remain that it's still a problem to use the `parfor` on the GPU;